# How do you get JAWs to stop reading keystrokes?

Tags: javascript, wai-aria, keystroke, jaws-screen-reader

I'm trying to add aria-labels to a webpage I'm making. I have an app listening for when a KeyCode is sent when you plug in headphones into an Audio Nav keyboard to traverse the webpage. I currently have JAWS defaultly configured to not read all but the keystrokes toggled as "Always Speak", but it is still reading the Shift key combinations and I'm not sure how to stop that from happening. It was working before when I ran it at first, but now it says the keystrokes every time. I already tried looking through the documentation and that was no help, since nothing on there seems to touch on this. Not even the tutorials. If someone could help me understand how to have it not do that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Greetings!  This might be more easily understood by the community if you could provide a [mcve] of code in the body of the question.  Without it, general direction _may_ be able to be provided, but it is less likely you will get an answer specific to your scenario that will help you.

Comment: Wow, so many things going on here that seem all unrelated. What does `aria-label` have to do with plugging in headphones?  And how is that related to typing?  JAWS can announce keystrokes but sometimes it depends what kind of element you're on.  In general, you can go to JAWS settings center > keyboard > general > manage key labels and tell JAWS which keystrokes to announce.  I have "tab" turned off (set to "mute"). My shift key, which I haven't touched, is set to "always speak".

Comment: Essentially, JAWS is not reading my default settings correctly. I have all keys set to mute, but it still speaks all the keys regardless if it's combined with a key set to "always speak"  -_- Apologies, I didn't completely understand how to articulate my issue. Have any of you ran into this issue before and, if so, know how it was fixed?